# Solspace color coding events by Category

Tags: solspace, channel, solspace-calendar, categories

I have a handful of events I need color coded.

**Here is my setup:** Solspace Calendar using the [Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) theme, and setup by using [this guide](http://adamrotman.com/blog/post/build-a-kick-ass-calendar-with-expressionengine-jquery/).

Currently, everything works beautifully.

I am gathering events by using *multiple* .ics files under the Calendar Module section. Each .ics file will be all the events for that category. ***Example:*** publicevents.ics would post all the Public Events, and publicmeetings.ics would post all the Public Meetings, and so on.

So far I've created all needed categories under Admin >> Channel Administration >> Categories.

**Here are my questions:**

1. Can I color code these events by category on the front end with this set up?
2. How would I link each separate .ics file to a class so that it can display that color?

I'm assuming I can just use...

`{if category_id="13"}
   class="category1"
{/if}`

...once I can figure out how to link each separate .ics file with a class?

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, after many many... many days (too many days) of trying to figure this out, I finally did and the answer was literally right under our noses the entire time. We just didn't search through Full Calendar's documentation long enough. It is incredibly simple.

```
color: 'yellow',
textColor: 'black'
```

[Full Calendar Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/)

Answer (score 1):

Calendar will not support the automated import/assigning of EE Categories through ICS import. You would have to enter these all in manually after the fact to get it to work.

I am not exactly sure how your workflow is, and how you're currently using the built in "calendars" option (where you create and manage calendars (channel entries) that events get assigned to), but I would suggest that you use calendars as your "categories" if possible. And because the use of calendars is expected, you'll have much better support for that functionality throughout the Calendar add-on. :)

Comment: Hi Solspace, thanks for the reply! Am I understanding this correctly: You're suggesting I create multiple calendars, each with its own .ics file with events? If so, would I be able to use a drop down box to select 'Public Events' but really it would be pulling a calendar ID with the public events .ics only? And for 'All Events', I would have another calendar ID with ALL .ics files? Even then... all of those events would still need to be color coded...

I'm so lost!!

Comment: Also: The calendar is setup through channels and using fields (I think this is default?). Hope I answered that correctly.

Comment: Oh!! I just had an idea. Can I create more .ics fields? How does your calendar determine the .ics field (is it `calendar_ics_url`)? Can I change this internally?

Comment: _Am I understanding this correctly: You're suggesting I create multiple calendars, each with its own .ics file with events?_ Yes. That's correct. For color-coding, you can use conditionals checking for calendar_id or calendar_name, and output the color you need depending on the id/name. And no, you cannot create more .ics fields: those fields wouldn't import data. So 1 calendar = 1 color = 1 .ics file.

Comment: Okay! This will work great. Except, I have one more question. Lets say I have a select/option area with these Categories (that are really just separate calendars), and I wanted to select 'ALL EVENTS'. How would color coding work in this case? Do I create another calendar with all .ics files? But... then we're back where we started trying to figure out how to color code all those categories. What am I missing here? Thanks for all of your time, Solspace.

Comment: If you don't provide a `calendar_id` or `calendar_name`, all events from all calendars would display in tags such as `{exp:calendar:cal}` or `{exp:calendar:events}`. The `{event_calendar_id}` variable is still available within these tags for color-coding according to calendar, though. Eg. `{if event_calendar_id = "123"}red{/if}{if event_calendar_id = "456"}green{/if}{if event_calendar_id = "789"}blue{/if}`. If you're using a dropdown to send a calendar_id to a template using Calendar tags, you could have an option with an empty value to send no particular calendar_id, i.e. "all events".

Comment: This is fantastic. I really appreciate all your time and help, Solspace!